# Ubuntu Installation taking over 3 hours

Tags: software-installation

Hey guys I newly built my pc and tried installing Ubuntu after realizing how amazing it is.
I have been on the install screen for 3 hours now I've seen people take 2 hours but it shouldn't really be taking that long for me because:

Specs that are factors

CPU: Intel Core i5-4690K 3.5GHz Quad-Core OEM/Tray Processor
Memory (RAM):G.Skill Ares Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory
Storage: Seagate Barracuda 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive

Comment: The installation process should take about 20 min, if that's what you wanted to know.

Comment: I just found out that if your press the up arrow key it shows what's going on in the back ground I got SquashfsErrors. I seen the page but it doesn't really tell me how to fix it do you think the problem might be the usb?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SquashfsErrors

Comment: You did not mention motherboard & video card/chip. Those make a lot of difference. And are you installing in UEFI or CSM mode? CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
2) If using a CD/DVD, did you burn the disc as slowly as possible?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto
3) Did you select the media check before trying to install?
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
4) Did you ever do a "memory check" (another live-media menu choice) on your PC?
Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with a bad install media.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing by connecting to an internet connection then it might install updates as well, so it depends on your internet connection. If that is not the issue then use Rufus to make a bootable stick and try again. It can never take more than 30 minutes to install Ubuntu. And please don't connect to internet while installing.